# Printing different values for the same Struct variable in C

Tags: c, struct

```
#define MAX_HEIGHT 512
#define MAX_WIDTH 512

typedef struct
{
  int lines;
  int cols;
  int highestValue;
  int matrix[MAX_WIDTH][MAX_HEIGHT];
} Pgm;

void getInfo()
{
  Pgm pgm;
  FILE *f = fopen("pepper.pgm", "r");
  bool keepReading = true;
  int line = 0, countSpaces = 0, i = 0;
  do
  {
    fgets(buffer, MAX_LINE, f);
    if (feof(f))
    {
      printf("\nCheguei no final do arquivo");
      keepReading = false;
      break;
    }
    if (line >= 3)
    {
      char *values = strtok(buffer, " ");
      while (values != NULL)
      {
        total++;
        // printf("values: %d, cols: %d, pgm.matrix[%d][%d], total: %d\n", atoi(values), pgm.cols, i, countSpaces, total);
        pgm.matrix[i][countSpaces] = atoi(values);
        if (i == pgm.lines && countSpaces == pgm.cols)
          break;
        countSpaces++;
        if (countSpaces == pgm.cols)
        {
          countSpaces = 0;
          i++;
        }
        values = strtok(NULL, " ");
      }
    }
    line++;
  } while (keepReading);
  fclose(f);
printf("cols: %d, lines: %d, highest: %d, matrix[0][0]: %d", pgm.cols, pgm.lines, pgm.highestValue, pgm.matrix[0][0]);
}

void resolveMatrix()
{
  Pgm pgm;
  printf("cols: %d, lines: %d, highest: %d", pgm.cols, pgm.lines, pgm.highestValue);
}
```

I have this `getInfo` function that reads a `.pgm` file and adds the values inside this file to a `matrix` inside my `struct`. When i do a printf statement inside such function it prints out the right values that i want. But when i try to do that inside another function it prints out diffent values. I think this has to do with memory addres, but how would i solve this :(

Comment: Where is the definition for pgm that is used in your getInfo() function?

Comment: Forgot to type it, now it should be good :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `resolveMatrix` function you are using the struct `pgm` without initializing it, so it will print random garbage that was on that memory location on the stack before the struct was created.

If you want to use a struct that was created somewhere else, pass a pointer to it as a function parameter:

```
void resolveMatrix(Pgm *pgm)
{
    printf("cols: %d, lines: %d, highest: %d", pgm->cols, pgm->lines, pgm->highestValue);
}
```

Usage:

```
Pgm pgm;

// Initialize struct fields here ...

resolveMatrix(&pgm);
```